# Unable to use Laravel Factory in Tinker

Tags: php, laravel, tinker, laravel-8

I am unable Model Factory in Laravel Tinker.

//ItemFactory.php

```
class ItemFactory extends Factory
{
    /**
     * The name of the factory's corresponding model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $model = Item::class;

    /**
     * Define the model's default state.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function definition()
    {
        return [
            'name' => $this->faker->name,
            'slug' => $this->faker->slug(5, true),
            'code' => $this->faker->words(5, true),
            'description' => $this->faker->sentence,
            'price' => $this->faker->randomNumber(1000, 10000),
            'size' => $this->faker->randomElement(['Small', 'Medium', 'Large',]),
        ];
    }
}
```

Inside Tinker

```
>>> factory(App\Item::class)->create();
```

It throws me an error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function factory() in Psy Shell
> code on line 1

Answer (score 17, accepted):

After going through the [documentation of Model Factory](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/database-testing#creating-models), there were major changes in **Laravel 8 version**.

For using Model Factory anywhere inside Laravel 8:

1. Inside Model, we need to import the `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory` trait
2. New command to implement the factory

```
App\Item::factory()->create();
```

Comment: `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory` In laravel 8 it's by default imported when make model using command

Answer (score 17):

In Laravel 8.x [release notes](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/releases):

> Eloquent model factories have been entirely re-written as class based
> factories and improved to have first-class relationship support.

Global `factory()` function is removed as of Laravel 8. Instead, you should now use [model factory classes](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/database-testing#creating-factories).

1. Create a factory:

```
php artisan make:factory ItemFactory --model=Item
```

2. Make sure that `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory` trait is imported in your model:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Item extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    // ...
}
```

3. Use it like this:

```
$item = Item::factory()->make(); // Create a single App\Models\Item instance

// or

$items = Item::factory()->count(3)->make(); // Create three App\Models\Item instances
```

Use `create` method to persist them to the database:

```
$item = Item::factory()->create(); // Create a single App\Models\Item instance and persist to the database

// or

$items = Item::factory()->count(3)->create(); // Create three App\Models\Item instances and persist to the database
```

---

Being said that, if you still want to provide support for the previous generation of model factories within Laravel 8.x, you can use [laravel/legacy-factories](https://github.com/laravel/legacy-factories) package.

Answer (score 17):

In laravel 8 the default route namespace was removed.

Try to change command

```
factory(App\Item::class)->create();
```

To

```
\App\Models\Item::factory()->create(); 
\App\Models\Item::factory(10)->create(); \\If you want to create specify number of record then
```

Comment: This worked great in Laravel 9 as well.

Comment: Thanks @Adam for share such a usefull information.I will help lot's of developer

Comment: Thanks it worked for me using laravel 9

Answer (score 1):

In Laravel 8 I couldn't get the factory method to work just calling it straight out but I was able to get it to work by calling it like a static method on the Item class:

Terminal:

Item::factory()->create();

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

In **laravel 10**

1. Make sure in your model *Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory* is imported your model should look like this

```
  use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
  
  class Item extends Model
  {
      use HasFactory;
  
      // ...
  }
```

Create a factory

> php artisan make:factory ItemFactory --model=Item

Define factory
In open tinker

> php artisan tinker

Then

> use App\Models\model-name(ie Item)
> Item::factory()->create()

To insert 4 records perhaps you can specify factory parameter

> item::factory(4)->create()